# PgBouncer and auth to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, pgbouncer

pgbouncer version 1.7.2

psql (9.5.6)

I try use auth_hba_file (/var/lib/pgsql/9.5/data/pg_hba.conf) in PgBouncer.

**Config pgbouncer.ini**

```
postgres = host=localhost port=5432 dbname=postgres user=postgres
test = host=localhost port=5432 dbname=test user=test
[pgbouncer]
logfile = /var/log/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.log
pidfile = /var/run/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.pid
listen_addr = *
listen_port = 6432
auth_type = hba
auth_hba_file = /var/lib/pgsql/9.5/data/pg_hba.conf
admin_users = postgres
stats_users = stats, postgres
pool_mode = session
server_reset_query = DISCARD ALL
max_client_conn = 100
default_pool_size = 20
```

**cat pg_hba.conf | grep -v "#" | grep -v "^$"**

```
local   all             all                              trust
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32     trust
host    all             all             ::1/128          trust
host    test            test            10.255.4.0/24    md5
```

**psql -h 10.233.4.16 -p 5432 -U test**

```
Password for user test:
psql (9.5.6)
Type "help" for help.

test=> \q
```

**psql -h 10.233.4.16 -p 6432 -U test**

```
psql: ERROR:  No such user: test
```

**tail -fn10 /var/log/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.log**

```
LOG C-0x78f7e0: (nodb)/(nouser)@10.255.4.245:8963 closing because: No such user: test (age=0)
WARNING C-0x78f7e0: (nodb)/(nouser)@10.255.4.245:8963 Pooler Error: No such user: test
LOG C-0x78f7e0: (nodb)/(nouser)@10.255.4.245:8963 login failed: db=test user=test
```

But i cannot connect to postgresql (using PgBouncer) using pg_hba.conf

Can somebody help? 
May you have example for use auth_hba_file.
Thanks

I changed config:

**[root@dev-metrics2 pgbouncer]# cat pgbouncer.ini | grep -v ";" | grep -v "^$" | grep -v "#"**

```
[databases]
postgres = host=localhost port=5432 dbname=postgres user=postgres
test = host=localhost port=5432 dbname=test auth_user=test
[pgbouncer]
logfile = /var/log/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.log
pidfile = /var/run/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.pid
listen_addr = *
listen_port = 6432
auth_query = SELECT usename, passwd FROM pg_shadow WHERE usename=$1
admin_users = postgres
stats_users = stats, postgres
pool_mode = session
server_reset_query = DISCARD ALL
max_client_conn = 100
default_pool_size = 20
```

**Drop and Create user and DB**

```
[local]:5432 postgres@postgres # DROP DATABASE test;
DROP DATABASE
[local]:5432 postgres@postgres # DROP USER test ;
DROP ROLE
[local]:5432 postgres@postgres # CREATE USER test with password 'test';
CREATE ROLE
[local]:5432 postgres@postgres # CREATE DATABASE test with owner test;
CREATE DATABASE
```

**PGPASSWORD=test psql -h 10.233.4.16 -p 6432 -U test**

```
Password for user test:
psql: ERROR:  Auth failed
```

**tail -fn1 /var/log/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.log**

```
LOG Stats: 0 req/s, in 0 b/s, out 0 b/s,query 0 us
LOG C-0x17b57a0: test/test@10.255.4.245:3069 login attempt: db=test user=test tls=no
LOG C-0x17b57a0: test/test@10.255.4.245:3069 closing because: client unexpected eof (age=0)
LOG C-0x17b57a0: test/test@10.255.4.245:3070 login attempt: db=test user=test tls=no
LOG C-0x17b57a0: test/test@10.255.4.245:3070 closing because: Auth failed (age=0)
WARNING C-0x17b57a0: test/test@10.255.4.245:3070 Pooler Error: Auth failed
```

Work config:

**cat pgbouncer.ini | grep -v ";" | grep -v "^$" | grep -v "#"**

```
[databases]
*= port=5432 auth_user=postgres
[pgbouncer]
logfile = /var/log/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.log
pidfile = /var/run/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.pid
listen_addr = *
listen_port = 6432
auth_query = SELECT usename, passwd FROM pg_shadow WHERE usename=$1
admin_users = postgres
stats_users = stats, postgres
pool_mode = session
server_reset_query = DISCARD ALL
max_client_conn = 100
default_pool_size = 20
```

Comment: using database hba for pgbouncer is perfectly fine. show us your error (from `/var/log/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.log`)

Comment: m! much better. please check if user test is in file, specified at `auth_file`, and if not (must be the case) add it, smth like `"test" "md564b76e462e88c4fa6898960d067845b8"` - you can find the hash from `select passwd from pg_shadow where usename = 'test';`

Comment: I update post. I used auth_query, but cannot connect to PostgreSQL :(

Comment: restarted pgbouncer? show the log - when you can't connect you get the message and log lines generated - they are essential to understand what's wrong

Comment: I changed config and he is work. :)

Comment: what was the issue?

Comment: issue - i dont know how setting auth_hba_file using mkauth.py. But i used auth_query and i think need close this question :)

Answer (score 0):

Try put space

```
*= port=5432 auth_user=postgres  # old string
* = port=5432 auth_user=postgres # new string
```

work for me